# Xamarin - Image from URI isn't rendered despite being seemingly downloaded

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

let me start by saying sorry if this is already answered somewhere, I searched for very long time and couldn't find an answer that works.

So as per title, I have a **very** simple app with literally one page that should display one image from URI and that's it. For some reason the image doesn't show up neither when deploying on a physical device nor on emulator. Image works fine, it's just a random image from web (http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/watercolor-autumn-forest-landscape-sunset-hand-drawn-painting-fantasy-art-nature-beautiful-background-gouache-153834924.jpg). I've attached ActivityIndicator that stops spinning after a second, so I would assume that the image is loaded, so it's not an issue with app not connecting to the web and simply image rendering...

I've tried setting Android Options -> Advanced -> HttpClient implementation to Managed and SSL/TLS implementation to Native TLS 1.2+, as well as Android Manifest -> Required Permissions -> Internet. Neither helped. I tried using http:// and https://, no results neither. I'm very confused at the moment.

Here's my App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using App1.Services;
using App1.Views;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
            MainPage = new ImagePage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's ImagePage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App1
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ImagePage : ContentPage
    {
        public ImagePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var imageSource = new UriImageSource { Uri = new Uri("http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/watercolor-autumn-forest-landscape-sunset-hand-drawn-painting-fantasy-art-nature-beautiful-background-gouache-153834924.jpg") };
            imageSource.CachingEnabled = false;

            image.Source = imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's xaml for this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.ImagePage">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference image}, Path=IsLoading}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 100, 100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
        <Image IsVisible="True" x:Name="image"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help :). As I said, this is extremely simple and I have no clue why this doesn't work at this point.

Comment: that url returns a HTTP 301.  I think you've picked a bad example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your `Xamarin.Forms` version ?There is an [issue reported](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7684) in Xamarin.forms version `4.2.0.778463` early and that it has been fixed in the Xamarin.forms version `4.2.0.848062`.

So you could try to update your `Xamarin.forms` version

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to be it. I had the exact version you mentioned here and update fixed the bug. It's strange how something like this could slip through. It's also strange I was unable to find this... anyway sorry and thanks!